# How do I delete a header with Privoxy?

Tags: headers, privoxy

How do I delete a header with Privoxy?  I know of the `add-header` action, but how do I do the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "crunch-client-header" For more information look [here](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html).